# Downloaded Songs from Itunes are now not downloaded

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I have around 600 songs downloaded on my PC from Apple Music, but now even on my phone all my downloads disappeared and need to download them again. I checked the Apple Computer Folder in AppData and it shows it has 5.7 GB and 661 files but when I open one of the folders it is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  How does the phone relate to the PC? Perhaps adding a screen  shot will make a bit more sense to us that do not see your settings and situation.

Comment: @bmike I am not sure how this connects to my Apple Music on my iPhone. I am talking about the little cloud icon you click on the song to downloaded. I had all my songs downloaded but I cannot play them and show with the cloud icon to download them again.